# Rename user account in SAM file

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

How to rename account in SAM? I try to rename account in Active Directory, but this action don't change account name in SAM file.

Comment: Do you mean the SAM file on the local computer? Or the samAccountName?

Comment: I mean SAM file on the local computer.

Comment: The Active Directory database and the local security database are completely separate authorities. Renaming an AD user account will have no effect on a local user account.

Comment: @joeqwerty I understand it. But I need renaming AD user account and corresponding local user account.

Comment: OK, I understand that's what you'd like, but it isn't possible.

Comment: @joeqwerty Why? Any stored data may be modified.

Comment: I think that I'm not understanding your question. Perhaps you can clarify what it is exactly that you're trying to accomplish. When you rename an AD user account you want a local user account also to be renamed? Or are you referring to the user profile?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, I want to rename AD account and a local user account simultaneously.